# Show sales figures over time per employee

Tags: excel

Assume the following data:

```
day employee sales
 1     a        0
 1     b       10
 1     c       10
 2     a        5
 2     b        7
 2     c       10
 3     a        3
 3     b        3
 3     c        5
```

I would like to have a chart with on the x-asis the days (1, 2, 3) and on the y-axis the number of sales. Each employee should have its own line, so they can be compared.

I am unable to get a chart like this. I expect to get 3 lines when selecting all data, but Excel returns 1 line per data-row instead. It does not, so to speak, group the sales by employee. How can I get the chart I want? Is it even possible?

Any help is greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Have you tried a pivot table or pivot chart? Just drop your employee name in your row section, sum your sales, and I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I will take me some fiddling, but this looks indeed what I need. Thanks!

Comment: In that case, I'll add that as an answer.  Green check away if it was what you needed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried a pivot table or pivot chart? Just drop your employee name in your row section, sum your sales, and I think that's what you're looking for.